# Moving from bower to npm and including css from node_modules - AngularJS Webpack Sass

Tags: css, angularjs, webpack

I have an AngularJS application that ran on a mix of Bower and Npm modules.

For instance I had used `angular-material-data-table` by using `bower install angular-material-data-table --save` and this added inline to my `index.html`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.css" />
```

This is my hierarchy for my app.

```
- app
- - scripts
- - styles
```

Inside styles I currently use `.scss` extension and have a `main.scss` file which I `@import` my files into which then gets processed.

I am now using Webpack too

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/scripts/app.module.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/build'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js'
    }
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.json$/,
        loaders: [
          'json-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|svg|ttf|png)([\?]?.*)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?minimize=true',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: [
          'ng-annotate-loader',
          'babel-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      "moment": "moment",
      "$": "jquery",
      "jQuery": "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })
  ],
  externals: ['window'],
  devtool: '#inline-source-map',
};
```

So I've tried

Adding into 
`app.module.js`

`import '../../node_modules/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.css';`

Also tried adding

`@import '/node_modules/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.css';` inside `main.scss`

Both of which do not work.

Comment: What means doesnt work? import '../../node_modules/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.css' should either work or return error.

Comment: Did you try `import '..\../../../node_modules/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.css';`?